# return of malloc() function

Tags: c, pointers

malloc() function is said to return a null pointer or a pointer to the allocated space. Suppose for a string we make the statement:

```
char* ptr =  malloc(size)
```

Isn't `ptr`  a pointer that would point to a pointer?
Isn't :

```
char** ptr = malloc(size)
```

supposed to be the correct way to declare the pointer to char?

The compiler however doesn't give a warning when we do either, the warning it does give is for the format specifier if used.

How should we declare this and why? Also, how would char** be used?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre that's not a valid upe here, I guess.

Comment: I should read the text and not only the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `char *` denotes a char pointer. Malloc will return a `void *` pointer (that will be automatically converted to whatever pointer you're trying to assign).

The `char **` denotes a `char *` pointer. This is a pointer to a pointer.

If you think of a pointer as a map you have that `char *` is a map to a char, `void *` is a map to something mysterious and `char **` is a map to another map that leads to a char. So

```
char* ptr = malloc(size);
```

Is the correct one, because you want a map to something, not a map to a map.

Comment: You should say "automatically converted", rather than "cast", to avoid confusion with the meaning of *cast* as an explicit conversion.

Comment: @NomeQueEuLembro , how would cast** would be used with malloc() or calloc(), could you please provide an example?

Comment: Thanks, @trentcl! Fixed.

Comment: @BumbleBee Let's say you want to allocate a 2D integer grid of size NxN. You could use int ** grid = malloc(N*sizeof * grid). You would still have to individually allocated every row of the grid with a loop too.

Answer (score 4):

No, 'ptr' would contain the pointer returned by 'malloc'. You are *assigning* the returned pointer, not taking its address.

Answer (score 1):

- `*ptr` is a pointer to a char, which is often used to manage an array
  or a string.
- `**ptr` is a pointer to a pointer to a char, which is often used to
  manage a matrix (array of arrays) or a string array.